# Is there a term for the person responsible for establishing the "tone" of a website?

Tags: website-design

We have a person on our team who has taken on the role of establishing the tone of our website. This includes the general style of the graphic design, the wording of our text...etc.

Is there a title for someone who does this? User Experience doesn't seem quite right, but maybe so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Designer. :-)

(In a traditional studio/agency setting this would partly be the task of an art director, a copywriter, and a creative planner. Lead and consolidated by a creative director.)

Answer (score 3):

Many roles would be responsible for this. As for a 'lead' it could be any number of (or combination of) rolls:

- product manager
- brand manager
- art director
- copywriter
- marketing director
- editor

And certainly, user experience could be the role as well. Alas, we work in an industry with rather loose job descriptions and titles, so there is no one 'right' answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

So far as the overall 'tone' of the site is concerned, it would appropriately be the Content Editor who takes care of presenting everything to suit the target audience and project the right brand image.